# Using display style fraction in a matrix environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, matrices, arrays

I'd like use the `\dfrac` command in a `bmatrix` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, one gets pretty ugly spaced elements that do not entirely fit between matrix brackets

[image]

Without specifying magic line skip values, what is the proper way to fix this problem?

Comment: Why not using `\cfrac{}{}` instead of `\dfrac{}{}`?

Comment: Are you suggesting the (mis)use of a command intended for continuous fractions? Why would that be a good choice? Please explain in an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can stick some `\strut`s in there (the height+depth of a paren):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\strut\partial f}{\strut\partial x}
    \\
    \dfrac{\strut\partial f}{\strut\partial y}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely most easy, without manual adjustment of spacing parameters - nice! Note that this solution also adds a bit vertical space around the fraction lines. (with `f` this is OK, but maybe not with `h` instead.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Yes, I tried with `\mathstrut` for `h`, but it looks wrong. Also, for the reader, I think my claim of a `\strut` being the height and depth of a paren is wrong (I think in LaTeX it is `.7\baselineskip` for height and `.3\baselineskip` for depth, and in plain they're fixed). IIRC, for the `\mathstrut` the claim would be correct.

Answer (score 49):

This answer consists of three parts:

- a solution with manual adjustment of the vertical spacing,
- a solution with a modified `\arraystretch` that automatically centers the brackets around the matrix properly (unlike the original `\arraystretch`!),
- an explanation of the ugly default spacing.

### The easy answer

You have two issues here:

1. The spacing is ugly – the matrix entries actually *overlap* slightly.
2. The matrix entries do not entirely fit between the brackets.

Issue #2 is in fact by design since you have a default `\delimitershortfall` of `5pt`, which means that at most `5pt` of the entries are not "covered" by the brackets. Thus, an easy solution (with manually adjusted vertical space, as in the first part of Gonzalo's answer) would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\delimitershortfall}{0pt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \\[2ex]
    \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: nicer matrix]

(The redefinition of `\delimitershortfall` is local to the displayed formula.) It is interesting to note that adding much less vertical space, say `0.5ex`, has *no effect whatsoever*; I will explain this near the bottom of the answer.

### Using `\arraystretch`

If your matrix has a lot of rows, adding `\\[2ex]` every time is annoying, and it becomes a nuisance when you want to adjust the spacing. In this case, percusse's idea to use `\arraystretch` is great *in principle*. The problem is, as percusse discovered: `\arraystretch` adds more space at the top of the matrix than at the bottom. This becomes very obvious if you take a large value, say `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}`:
[image: \arraystretch example]

Gonzalo offers a manual adjustment for this in the second part of his answer, but it would be nicer if it just worked out of the box! The *cause* for the peculiar behaviour of `\arraystretch` lies in it's implementation, which is suitable for text arrays, but not for math arrays as I'll explain at the end of the answer.

In the code below I offer a `\CenteredArraystretch` command that takes as mandatory argument the desired `\arraystretch`. In the image I compare `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}`, `\CenteredArraystretch{2.5}` and `\CenteredArraystretch{2.1}`. The latter is quite agreeable in my opinion:

[image: comparison of 3 versions]

Note that with `\arraystretch` you usually won't have to modify `\delimitershortfall` any more! The code works by hacking into LaTeX's `array` and needs `etoolbox` for patching `\@mkpream`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifcenter@asb@\center@asb@false
\def\center@arstrutbox{%
    \setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{$\vcenter{\box\@arstrutbox}$}%
    }
\newcommand*{\CenteredArraystretch}[1]{%
    \ifcenter@asb@\else
      \pretocmd{\@mkpream}{\center@arstrutbox}{}{}%
      \center@asb@true
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}%
    }
\makeatother
\newcommand*\testvector{
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
      \\
      \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
    \end{bmatrix}
    }
\begin{document}
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
  \testvector
  \CenteredArraystretch{2.5}
  \testvector
  \CenteredArraystretch{2.1}
  \testvector
\]
\end{document}
```

### Why is the default spacing so ugly?

The reason for the slight *overlap* is that `\partial` sticks out of its bounding box a little; in the image I show only the top and the bottom:
[image: bounding box of \partial]

But why are the two fractions just put on top of each other by default? The reason lies in the implementation of `bmatrix`, which is based on the LaTeX `array`. (The plain TeX `\matrix` would put a vertical space of `1pt` between the fractions!)

Here's how `array` works: Each row gets a *minimum* height and a *minimum* depth, defined by the height and depth of `\strutbox`. If the actual height and depth of your entries are larger, then the `\strutbox` has no effect. (This is the case for the displaystyle fractions.) Then the rows are just put on top of each other, without additional vertical space. This implementation results in good spacing only if the actual material in the rows has "usual" small height and depth.

Now I can explain why `\\[0.5ex]` has no effect in the first part of my answer: simply put, the `0.5ex` are just added to the depth of the `\strutbox` (`3.6pt`), and together this is still less than the depth of `\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}` (`6.86pt`). Thus, you'll only get an effect if you add more that `3.26pt` vertical space!

Moreover, I can explain why `\arraystretch` adds too much space at the top of the matrix: LaTeX increases both the height and the depth of the `\strutbox` by the factor `\arraystretch`. Now the point is that the height (`8.4pt`) is much larger than the depth (`3.6pt`), so with an `\arraystretch` of `2`, `8.4pt` are added at the top of the matrix, and only `3.6pt` at the bottom. For a text array this should be OK, but in a matrix things tend to be centered vertically with respect to the mathematical axis (like fractions and integrals), so when they get large, they have equal increase in height and depth.

What I don't know is *why* the above implementation of `array` was chosen in LaTeX. I guess that for text arrays it makes a lot of sense, but it appears that it's not optimal for matrices.

Comment: I like the second answer, but when I use `\usepackage{siunitx}`, the spacing is messed up (much too close) with Tex Live 2018 and LuaLaTex. Does anybody else have this problem?

Comment: Where goes the argument that the advantage of using LaTeX is that it lets you to concentrate on writing, and spend less time on presentation? Sorry for sarcasm. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the optional argument of `\\` to add vertical space and some zero-width rules to increase the length of the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\rule{0pt}{1.7em}
  \\[1em]
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\rule[-1.2em]{0pt}{0em}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Building on percusses's idea, you could define a new environment increasing `\arraystretch` and adding some extra space for the last row. The first (optional) argument in my example controls the redefinition of `\arraystretch`; the second (mandatory) argument controls the spacing after the last row:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\myfact{}
\newenvironment{Mybmatrix}[2][1.8]
  {\renewcommand\myfact{#2}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}\begin{bmatrix}}
  {\\[-\myfact em]\mbox{}\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{Mybmatrix}{2}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{Mybmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know, however, how "robust" this definition will be.

Comment: As already mentioned, I'd like to avoid this. Also, the problem with elements not fitting entirely into the matrix which can be seen in the question persists.

Comment: @caustic: I've updated my answer with a possible solution for the elements not fitting. I don't know if there is a more automated solution.

Comment: btw: this has nothing to do with mathtools, `\dfrac` stem from `amsmath` (if it isn't in the LaTeX core). `mathtools` automatically load `amsmath`

Comment: @daleif: I've updated the question.

Comment: @caustic: I've updated my answer with a new approach, using @percusses's idea.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following frequently which might be what you wish. But it still lacks the extra space at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ { \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The environments of `nicematrix` have two keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` inspired by the parameters `cellspacetoplimit` and `cellspacebottomlimit` of `cellspace`. There is also a key `cell-space-limit` to fix both parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This works for me exactly how one would expect from standard environments. Underrated answear

Answer (score 2):

The `tabstackengine` package allows you to set the baselineskip explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}% NOT NEEDED FOR THIS MWE, BUT USEFUL
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{30pt}
\bracketVectorstack{
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
}
\qquad
\setstackgap{L}{38pt}
\bracketVectorstack{
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: load the `cellspace` package with option `[math]`.  It lets you define a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, which already defines an `S`column type).
The `[math]` option extends this padding to the various matrix environments from `amsmath`.

Another interesting (and complementary) possibility is the `\mfrac` command (medium-sized fraction, ~80 % of `\displaystyle`) from `nccmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\[ A = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} \]

\[ B = \begin{bmatrix}
\mfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\mfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I define a new environment `+bmatrix` using the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). You can also adjust the `rowsep` in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{+bmatrix}[1][2pt]{%
  \hbox{$\left[
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\BODY]{
    rowsep = #1, colsep = 5pt,
    column{1} = {leftsep = 0pt},
    column{Z} = {rightsep = 0pt}, % last column
  }
    \BODY
  \end{tblr}
  \right]$}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Using \texttt{bmatrix} without rowsep}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\section{Using \texttt{+bmatrix} with default \texttt{rowsep=2pt}}

\[
\begin{+bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{+bmatrix}
\]

\section{Using \texttt{+bmatrix} with \texttt{rowsep=4pt}}

\[
\begin{+bmatrix}[4pt]
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{+bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]