# Vertical spacing between fractions in matrix environment

Tags: spacing, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase the line spacing in a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix)
>   [Using display style fraction in a matrix environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/using-display-style-fraction-in-a-matrix-environment)
>   [How to add extra spaces between rows in tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment)

When a fraction is used in a `matrix` environment, not enough vertical space is put between the rows. [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays) recommends using the `\em` command, but this seems like an inelegant solution. Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would have, but this seems like such an obvious scenario that an MWE isn't necessary and actually clutters the question. Am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables

Comment: @Quinn: MWEs are *always* welcome and *definitely* encouraged, since subjective views may interpret questions differently.

Comment: Yeah I realize it is not that hard, but anyone who wants to provide a solution will have to create it to test it and if you provide one to start there is less chance of misinterpretations.

Answer (score 33):

One approach is to add extra space between specific lines, with an optional argument to `\\`:

```
\left[\begin{matrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\
    \frac{5}{2} & \frac{7}{2}
\end{matrix}\right]
```

produces
[image]

While

```
\left[\begin{matrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\[6pt]
    \frac{5}{2} & \frac{7}{2}
\end{matrix}\right]
```

produces
[image]

Comment: Note that the OP wanted to avoid this approach

Comment: @cmhughes: Hm, I didn't see that in the post. Where was it stated?

Comment: *Wikibooks recommends using the \em command, but this seems like an inelegant solution*. No big deal though, it gets the job done :)

Comment: OK, I did see that, so I guess my question is... is `\em` equivalent to \\?

Comment: The Wikibooks link recommends using `\\[0.3em]` and you used `\\[6pt]`. The similarity (in my mind) is that both are manual approaches.

Comment: Ah... I thought `\em` was a macro rather than a unit!

Comment: @cmhughes -- `em` is a horizontal measure; better would be `ex` since it is a vertical measure.  wikibooks should be corrected.

Comment: @jtbandes -- `\em` *is* a macro; an old one meaning "emphasize" (usually resulting in italic). `em` is the em width of the current font, typically 10pt for a 10pt font.

Comment: This is great, when you don't want to change it for all matrices, because not all matrices will contain fractions, sums, products or similar big things.

Answer (score 19):

If you use an `array` environment then you can use the command

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
```

and tweak it to whatever you would like. I have loaded the `amsmath` package to use `\dfrac`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Default:
\[
    \left[
         \begin{array}{ccc}
         \dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6} & 0           \\
         \dfrac{5}{6} & 0           & \dfrac{1}{6} \\
         0           & \dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6}
        \end{array}
    \right]
\]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
Stretched:
\[
    \left[
         \begin{array}{ccc}
         \dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6} & 0           \\
         \dfrac{5}{6} & 0           & \dfrac{1}{6} \\
         0           & \dfrac{5}{6} & \dfrac{1}{6}
        \end{array}
    \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But isn't this bad because it used `array` where `matrix` is more appropriate?

Comment: @Quinn: that's up to you! If you'd prefer to use `matrix` then have a look at the links that people have posted as comments

Comment: This works for more than two lines as it centers the middle lines.

Answer (score 1):

In plain-tex format at least, `\matrix` calls `\normalbaselines`, which resets the `(base)lineskip(limit)`'s to `normal(base)lineskip(limit)`'s. Plain also has a macro called `\openup<dimen>` which increases the `(base)lineskip(limit)`'s by given `<dimen>`.

So it would seem logical to define a macro `\openupnormal`, which would do the same as `\openup`, only for `normal(base)lineskip(limit)`'s:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\openupnormal{\afterassignment\@penupnormal\dimen@=}
\def\@penupnormal{\advance\normallineskip\dimen@
  \advance\normalbaselineskip\dimen@
  \advance\normallineskiplimit\dimen@}
\catcode`@=12
```

so that one could do:

```
$$
  \left[
    \openupnormal1\jot\matrix{ % inside this group, increase the
                               % normal(base)lineskip(limit)'s by 1 jot
      {5\over6} & {1\over6} & 0 \cr
      {5\over6} & 0 & {1\over6} \cr
      0 & {5\over6} & {1\over6} \cr
    } % the group ends here, and so does the effect of \openupnormal
  \right]
  \quad
  \left[
    \matrix{
      {5\over6} & {1\over6} & 0 \cr
      {5\over6} & 0 & {1\over6} \cr
      0 & {5\over6} & {1\over6} \cr
    }
  \right]
$$
\bye
```

[image]

(Note that there is no `\displaystyle` in effect in the above fractions, unlike in `\dfrac`)

Comment: I use LaTeX, not plain-TeX. Will this still work? Is there an analogous solution for LaTeX?

Comment: I tried it with LaTeX and no errors. But I suppose you'd write things differently with LaTeX (`\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` instead of `\catcode`'s, `\frac`/`\dfrac` instead of `{x\over y}`, `\\[`/`\\]` instead of `$$` etc.