# How do I get normal-sized fractions in my matrices?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I would like to write something like the definition of a gradient operator in cartesian coordinates.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{equation}
    \nabla \Phi =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} \\
        \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y} \\
        \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

The fractions are rendered small, as when they are rendered inline, but I don't like it in that particular instance.

I knew this would happen since it is documented there: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

Even if I increase the spacing by adding [0.5em] after the double-backslash, it still doesn't look very good.  I have a lot of space so I'd like the content of the matrix not to squeeze itself.

How can I make the content of a matrix using its normal size and not its inline size?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `\dfrac` macro renders fractions as those in displayed math, even if it is part of an inline equation, fraction, or other setting where LaTeX prefers to typeset an inline version.

Conversely, I frequently find myself using `\tfrac`, which renders fractions in an inline (or "text mode") fashion even if the setting is display mode, because I often find the large fractions distracting from what is important in my equations.

As with most useful but basic macros for mathematics, these are provided by the `amsmath` package.

**Example code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Some fractions in inline math:
\( \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} \bigg/ \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \bigg/ \tfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} \)

\vspace{1ex}
Some fractions in displayed math (in and outside of some environments):
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{split}
    \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} \bigg/ \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \bigg/ \tfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}           \\
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \tfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{split}
  \qquad
  \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2} \\[2ex] \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \\[2ex]  \tfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}
  \end{cases}   \\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image: Sample images of fractions]

Comment: Adding to Niel de Beaudrap’s answer, you might find display-style fractions run against each other in matrices. Use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}` after `\begin{pmatrix}` if you need to expand the matrix. `1.25` is just a suggested stretch value; play around with it to find what looks best in your document.

Comment: @AstroPig7: See also [Using display style fraction in a matrix environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19457). Note that although `\arraystretch` is an excellent suggestion, it doesn't _quite_ do what one would expect.

Comment: Sometimes I astound myself with my blockheadedness- I've been writing things like $a \cdot \begin{LARGE}\frac{b}{c}\end{LARGE}$ for years...

Comment: Related: `\nicefrac`