# Brace and Array with \frac and \cos, Height

Tags: arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using display style fraction in a matrix environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/using-display-style-fraction-in-a-matrix-environment)

How do I create a left brace for an array such that it surrounds all the elements of the array? This is happening whenever one of the elements is \cos with \frac as its mandatory argument.

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}} \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
\cos\frac{2\pi}{n} \\
\vdots \\
\cos\frac{2\pi(n-1)}{n}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can gather, the various solutions are: placing \struts in the argument of the fractions, applying \arraystretch, and inserting lines with narrow height to increase the spacing manually. The cause of the issue is characters being drawn outside of the bounding box.