# Nested matrices; inner matrices too tall when switching math font

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, mathtools

I have used this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61290/46626 to adjust my matrices and it works fine with the standard font (Latin Modern Math)

[image: Matrix correct]

But when I use Cambria Math, the inner matrices seem to be too tall:

[image]

I am not able to fix that, does anybody have an idea? Is it possible to use it as an standard matrix style? I am using TeX Live 2016 and LuaLaTeX. Other solution for a proper setting of this matrices are also welcome. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools} % includes: \usepackage{amsmath} (-> needed e.g. for bmatrix) !! load BEFORE \usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   %Unicode mathematics support for X∃TEX and LuaTEX

%% Set font 
%\setromanfont{Cambria}
%\setsansfont{Calibri}
%\setmonofont{Consolas}
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifcenter@asb@\center@asb@false
\def\center@arstrutbox{%
\setbox\@arstrutbox\hbox{$\vcenter{\box\@arstrutbox}$}%
}
\newcommand*{\CenteredArraystretch}[1]{%
\ifcenter@asb@\else
  \pretocmd{\@mkpream}{\center@arstrutbox}{}{}%
  \center@asb@true
\fi
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\CenteredArraystretch{1.2}     
\delimitershortfall=-2pt %\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2} %Default is 1.0
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        m & 0\\
        0 & m
        \end{bmatrix}&
        -m\, \mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{-}y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}\\
        -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    -m
    \begin{bmatrix}
        y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} & -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \mathbfit{A}^{LR}&
    J^L + m\left(\left(x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}\right)^2 + 
                 \left(y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}\right)^2
           \right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot{x}^R_{O_LO_R}\\
    \ddot{y}^R_{O_LO_R}
    \end{bmatrix}\\%[2ex]
    \ddot{\psi}
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum
    \begin{bmatrix}
       F^R_{ix}\\
       F^R_{iy}
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    \sum M^L_{iz}+\sum 
    \begin{bmatrix}
       -y^L_{PiP} & 
        x^L_{PiP}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
       F^L_{ix}\\
       F^L_{iy}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
m\,\mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \begin{bmatrix}
       x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}\\
       y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix}
\dot{\psi}^2\\%[2ex]
0
\end{bmatrix}   
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**
Using Mico's answer, I (almost) found the desired result. But it needs a lot of manual adjustment and I wonder if there is a simpler solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools} % includes: \usepackage{amsmath} (-> needed e.g. for bmatrix) !! load BEFORE \usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   %Unicode mathematics support for X∃TEX and LuaTEX

% Set font 
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}


\begin{document}
\begin{multline} 
\delimitershortfall=-2pt \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.33} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\delimitershortfall=5pt
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        m & 0\\
        0 & m
    \end{bmatrix} &
    -m\, \mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \delimitershortfall=5pt
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{-}y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} \\
                  -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix} \\[3ex]
    -m \begin{bmatrix}
         y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} & 
        -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
       \end{bmatrix}
    \mathbfit{A}^{LR} &
    J^L + m\bigl(
              (x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L})^2 + 
              (y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L})^2 
           \bigr)
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
\delimitershortfall=5pt
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \ddot{x}^R_{O_LO_R}\\
      \ddot{y}^R_{O_LO_R}
    \end{bmatrix} \\[3.25ex]
    \ddot{\psi}
\end{bmatrix} \\[2ex]  % end of first row
\delimitershortfall=-2pt
=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
        F^R_{ix} \\[0.5ex]
        F^R_{iy}
     \end{bmatrix}\\
\sum\limits_{i} M^L_{iz}+
\sum\limits_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
        -y^L_{PiP} & x^L_{PiP}
     \end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix}
        F^L_{ix} \\[0.5ex] F^L_{iy}
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
m\,\mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} \\[0.5ex]
        y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix}
\dot{\psi}^2 \\[4.5ex]
0
\end{bmatrix}   
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image: new solution]

Comment: The first row in the upper screenshot is much wider than the textblock. Is this intentional? Aside: Is `\sum` correct? Should it maybe be `\Sigma`? Please advise.

Comment: BTW, `\setromanfont` is deprecated; use `\setmainfont` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The sum is correct (sum of forces/moments). I'm sorry that was a typo, i just upgraded from TeXLive2017 to TeXLive2018 before posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

(Tested with LuaLaTeX from TeXLive2018. Note: LuaTeX and `unicode-math` have evolved greatly between TeXLive2016 and TeXLive2018. If at all feasible, do consider updating to TeXLive2018.)

I don't think it's necessary to change `\delimitershortfall`, which is a the very-low-level parameter. Instead, change the value of `\arraystretch` and add a few extra vertical spacing directives as needed. Since there's no obvious alignment point across rows, I'd use a `multline` environment instead of the nested equation/split environments. Also, no need to use `\left` and  `\right` to auto-size some of the parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Set fonts 
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.33} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        m & 0\\
        0 & m
    \end{bmatrix} &
    -m\, \mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{-}y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} \\
                  -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix} \\[3ex]
    -m \begin{bmatrix}
         y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} & 
        -x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
       \end{bmatrix}
    \mathbfit{A}^{LR} &
    J^L + m\bigl(
              (x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L})^2 + 
              (y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L})^2 
           \bigr)
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \ddot{x}^R_{O_LO_R}\\
      \ddot{y}^R_{O_LO_R}
    \end{bmatrix} \\[3.25ex]
    \ddot{\psi}
\end{bmatrix} \\[2ex]  % end of first row
=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum \begin{bmatrix}
        F^R_{ix} \\[0.5ex]
        F^R_{iy}
     \end{bmatrix}\\
\sum M^L_{iz}+
\sum \begin{bmatrix}
        -y^L_{PiP} & x^L_{PiP}
     \end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix}
        F^L_{ix} \\[0.5ex] F^L_{iy}
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
m\,\mathbfit{A}^{RL}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L} \\[0.5ex]
        y^L_{P_{\mathrm{COG}}O_L}
    \end{bmatrix}
\dot{\psi}^2 \\[4.5ex]
0
\end{bmatrix}   
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this already looks really good with the `multiline` environment. There is only one problem left, I used `\delimitershortfall` in order to get the outer matrix bigger than the inner (in my opinion it looks ugly how the matrix above `\ddot{\psi}` protrudes the outer). If I insert `\delimitershortfall`, I have the same problem as in the question. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Konne - Try setting `\delimitershortfall=-1pt` and, in turn, not changing the value of `\arraystretch`. The brackets around the inner arrays in the upper row will no longer protrudevertically; they will still protrude, but only barely noticeably, in the lower row. About the summation symbols: To make it clear(er) to readers that summations are being applied, consider changing `\sum` to `sum_i` (or whater the appropriate summation index is).

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the sum. Unfortunately e.g. the ` m & 0\\0 & m` matrix is still too tall. I found a solution, but many `\delimitershortfall` commands are needed :(. I will add this to the question.