# How to I prevent fractions from getting stacked together in a matrix environment?

Tags: matrices, arrays

Below is my code. I have tried using the arraystretch but it is not working well for my document since it affects all the tables and matrices I dont want to adjust. I also tried some techniques from this link [Using display style fraction in a matrix environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/using-display-style-fraction-in-a-matrix-environment/19460) but I failed to achieve the results I want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            5 & 6 & 7 \\
            0 & 2 &  \\
            4 & 8 & 
        \end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{327}{78} & \frac{132}{7} & \frac{312}{17} \\
            \frac{32}{7} & \frac{32}{7} &  \\
            \frac{32}{7} & \frac{32}{7} & 
        \end{bmatrix}+&\begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7} \\
            -\frac{25}{7} & -\frac{25}{7} &  \\
            \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7}&\end{bmatrix}+&\begin{bmatrix}
            -1 & 0 & 1 \\
            -1 & 1 &  \\
            -2 & 2 & 
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\arraystretch`, but confine the change to this math environment.

```
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\begin{alignat*}{2}...\end{alignat*}}
```

Note the braces `{...}` surrounding the whole expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
   {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}%
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            5 & 6 & 7 \\
            0 & 2 &  \\
            4 & 8 & 
        \end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{327}{78} & \frac{132}{7} & \frac{312}{17} \\
            \frac{32}{7} & \frac{32}{7} &  \\
            \frac{32}{7} & \frac{32}{7} & 
        \end{bmatrix}+&\begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7} \\
            -\frac{25}{7} & -\frac{25}{7} &  \\
            \frac{10}{7} & \frac{10}{7}&\end{bmatrix}+&\begin{bmatrix}
            -1 & 0 & 1 \\
            -1 & 1 &  \\
            -2 & 2 & 
        \end{bmatrix}
      \end{alignat*}%
     }
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much @gernot. it worked